# Внешний вид приложения с боковой панелью с кнопками

Tags: c#, wpf

Разбираюсь с WPF. Хочу, чтобы в приложении была боковая панель с кнопками. По нажатию на кнопку (пункт меню) изменялось остальное содержимое окна.

Внимание вопрос: как скомпоновать элементы рабочей области? Подозреваю, что с исп. `Grid`, `WrapPanel` и т.д. Но не уверен. Может у кого ссылки есть полезные или добрый совет юному падавану?

Comment: Посмотрите, какие есть [layout-элементы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Panels_derived_elements). Боковую панель легко организовать при помощи `Grid`, да.

Comment: И не забывайте о существовании UserControl'ов. Не кладите весь UI в один XAML. Как код делится на функции и классы, так XAML делится на UserControl'ы.

Comment: @VladD, да вы правильно меня поняли, хоть я и не совсем корректно поставил вопрос. Читаю про UserControl, похоже это то, что я искал. Спасибо.

Comment: Приходите, спрашивайте. Обязательно выясните, что такое MVVM. Плюс там ещё есть такая мегавиртуальность как `DataTemplate` + `ContentPresenter`, позволяет автоматически выбирать UI в зависимости от данных.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно, чтобы при нажатии на элемент в списке изменялось содержимое справа от списка, то описанное вами очень похоже на `TabControl` с `TabStripPlacement=Left`. Если вам нужны табы, которые выглядят как кнопки, то этого можно достичь с помощью стилей:

```
<Style TargetType="TabControl">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                            <ToggleButton Margin="0 0 2 2" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            </ToggleButton>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

При подключении этого стиля следующий `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
    <TabItem Header="Foo">
        <TextBlock Text="Foo Content"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Bar">
        <TextBlock Text="Bar Content"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Baz">
        <TextBlock Text="Baz Content"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

будет выглядеть таким образом:

[image]

P.S. Замучался из-за попыток заставить `ContentPresenter` работать внутри батона. По отдельности или внутри бордера он табы переключает, а если положить в батон, то перестаёт работать. Но байндинг `IsChecked=IsSelected` решил проблему.

**Обновление**

Общая идея в том, что по возможности следует использовать максимум от стандартных контролов, а не изобретать велосипед. Отображение очень хорошо настраивается за счёт стилей и шаблонов, поэтому часто можно полагаться на стандартные контролы. Стандартные стили и шаблоны доступны в MSDN, а также выковыриваются с помощью Blend, поэтому можно модифицировать их сколько душа пожелает.

Comment: Я не совсем корректно поставил вопрос. На мой вопрос ответили выше. Про TabControl знал. Но то, что можно сделать панель сбоку + элементы оформить в виде кнопок - нет. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

**Используя MVVM**

Во View нужно забайндить элементы содержимого окна на свойства ViewModel, а кнопки на команды. При выполнении команды меняют св-ва.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WpfApplication.ViewModels"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:ViewModel></viewModels:ViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="1" Command="{Binding Command1}"></Button>
            <Button Content="2" Command="{Binding Command2}"></Button>
            <Button Content="3" Command="{Binding Command3}"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Green">
            <Viewbox >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"></TextBlock>
            </Viewbox>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _content;

        public string Content
        {
            get { return _content; }
            set
            {
                _content = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand Command1
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(() => Content = "1");
            }
        }
        public ICommand Command2
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(() => Content = "2");
            }
        }
        public ICommand Command3
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(() => Content = "3");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Выглядит это так:

[image]

Comment: А что такое `NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator`, Ваше Величество?

Comment: Этот атрибут проставил решарпер, он не обязателен. Используется для автоматической генерирации кода с нотификациями для свойств.